# How to use find -exec in CMake execute_process?

Tags: linux, find, installation, cmake, exec

I use CMake `install(DIRECTORIES...)` form to copy headers on install:

```
install(DIRECTORIES ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
  DESTINATION include
  FILES_MATCHING PATTERN "*.h")
```

However, this command [does create empty directories](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2010-July/038310.html) (those where no headers are found). Thus, I want to find and delete those empty directories during the install process:

```
install(CODE "execute_process(
  COMMAND find -type d -empty -exec rmdir '{}' ';'
  WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX}
  ERROR_FILE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/prune_empty_dirs.err)")
```

With the command above, the file `prune_empty_dirs.err` contains:

```
find: missing argument to `-exec'
```

I tried to escape the braces but it yields the same behavior. What am I doing wrong? Thanks,

Comment: You have a typo in WORKING_DIREC**OTIR**

Comment: Thanks @ixSci I fixed it; however the typo is in the question not in my script!

Comment: did you try this command without '' or with double ''? `-exec rmdir {} ;` or with `-exec rmdir ''{}'' '';''` or `-exec \"rmdir {} ;\"`

Comment: @ixSci I tried the possible ways of quoting you suggested, but they all give the same failure :-/ However, It did get to do what I seek by executing `bash` with the `find` command as argument to `-c`; thanks for your help

Comment: I'd suggest you to not create folders in a first place instead of removing them later. You can do it with FILE(GLOB) - get all files you need, then test output if it contains anything, and if it doesn't then just do not execute INSTALL(DIRECTORIES)

Comment: I know, but I'm not confident with the `file(GLOB)` command; the documentation states: `We do not recommend using GLOB to collect a list of source files from your source tree. If no CMakeLists.txt file changes when a source is added or removed then the generated build system cannot know when to ask CMake to regenerate.`

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. It is not the "{}" rather than the delemiting ";". The following syntax worked for me (CMake 2.8.9):

```
--exec rm {} "\;"
```

Comment: Came across this in the review queue, looks dangerous, but I need to learn more about cmake. Can you explain a little further?

Comment: It seems that the solution is to escape the `;` but not surrounding it with quotes when invoking the `find` command within the `install()` code (otherwise the string is truncated).