# CMake add_custom_target COMMAND find files and exec

Tags: cmake, command-line, jarsigner, add-custom-target

I have a .cmake file and I have a custom target in which I need to add a command to find and sign apk files. I do the following:

```
add_custom_target(${APK_BUILD_TARGET} ALL

  COMMAND find ${APK_DIR} -name "*.apk" -exec jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myKey.keystore -storepass myStorePass -keypass myKeyPass {} myName \;

)
```

I keep getting the error

> find: missing argument to `-exec'

If I execute the command alone, in a console, it works fine. I have the same problem with a simple echo command:

```
COMMAND find ${APK_DIR} -name "*.apk" -exec echo {} \;
```

I assume something is missing when doing that in COMMAND of add_custom_target, but what?

**EDIT:**

This work for echo command but not for jarsigner which still gives the previous error:

```
COMMAND find ${APK_DIR} -name "*.apk" -exec echo {} +
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following this post
[How to use find -exec in CMake execute_process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15020830/how-to-use-find-exec-in-cmake-execute-process)

I finally got the correct command line:

```
add_custom_target(${APK_BUILD_TARGET} ALL

  COMMAND find ${APK_DIR} -name "*.apk" -exec jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore myKey.keystore -storepass myStorePass -keypass myKeyPass {} myName "\;"

)
```

So with "\;" instead of just \;